# Problem with content/type: image/jpeg in IE

Tags: php, image, header

let's assume i have `some.jpg` file. 
I have a problem when try to do the following

```
$data   = file_get_contents(path/to/my/some.jpg);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $data;
exit();
```

this doesn't work in IE.It doesn't show the image (tested in version 8)

What is the problem?

Thanks much

**UPDATE**

the script i've written is the part of php script, which re-size the image(generates new image, if new size less than original size)

you can see it's working [here](http://www.tours.am/cms/image.php?image=http://www.tours.am/images/agency_logos/17/logo_raqyah.jpg&width=140)

my original image has the size `145`

if i set the new width more then it's original size, then it's doesn't show in ie, and it's the script i have shown above

i.e it's not working if i set new width greater then 145, for example [here](http://www.tours.am/cms/image.php?image=http://www.tours.am/images/agency_logos/17/logo_raqyah.jpg&width=148)

Comment: You see "ÿØÿà" in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works in Firefox, but not in IE, my guess is going to be you are passing through a CMYK JPEG, which IE can't display. Try a different image.

If it works in no browser, take a look at the source code of the file. There might be PHP error messages in there that you don't see because of the content type header.

Comment: @Syom yup, it's a CMYK image when you specify a size > 140. IE can't deal with those. If you specify a size smaller than its original size, it's an RGB one. No idea why, must have to do with the input image that your script chooses

Answer (score 2):

It's because IE sends

```
Content-Type: image/pjpeg
```

for *.jpg files.